enable decorator when define models in watermelondb on react
when define a model in watermelondb react js, show this error message:
[plugin:vite:react-babel] C:\xampp\htdocs\web-desktop\src\Resource\DB\WaterMelon\Models\Post.jsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators' isn't currently enabled (9:5):
Add @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-decorators (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-decorators) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
If you already added the plugin for this syntax to your config, it's possible that your config isn't being loaded.
You can re-run Babel with the BABEL_SHOW_CONFIG_FOR environment variable to show the loaded configuration:
npx cross-env BABEL_SHOW_CONFIG_FOR=C:\xampp\htdocs\web-desktop\src\Resource\DB\WaterMelon\Models\Post.jsx 
See https://babeljs.io/docs/configuration#print-effective-configs for more info.
C:/xampp/htdocs/web-desktop/src/Resource/DB/WaterMelon/Models/Post.jsx:9:4
7  |          comments: { type: 'has_many', foreignKey: 'post_id' },
8  |      }
9  |      @text('title') title
   |              ^
10 |      @text('body') body
11 |      @field('is_pinned') isPinned

this is my model:
import {children, date, field, text} from '@nozbe/watermelondb/decorators'
import {Model} from "@nozbe/watermelondb";

class Post extends Model {
    static table = 'posts'
    static associations = {
        comments: { type: 'has_many', foreignKey: 'post_id' },
    }
    @text('title') title
    @text('body') body
    @field('is_pinned') isPinned
    @date('archived_at') archivedAt
    @children('comments') comments
    get isRecentlyArchived() {
        // in the last 7 days
        return this.archivedAt &&
            this.archivedAt.getTime() > Date.now() - 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
    }

}
export default Post

this is my package:
{
  "name": "vite-dash",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.20",
    "@nozbe/watermelondb": "^0.27.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "draggable": "^4.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.4.6",
    "i18next": "^23.11.5",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.11",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.45",
    "notistack": "^3.0.1",
    "persian-tools": "^0.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.11",
    "swr": "^2.2.5",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.24.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}


This question is similar to: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators' isn't currently enabled (8:3):. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
